# Shutdown or Reboot a WSL session from inside the WSL session

Tags: bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to be able to reboot WSL sessions. To do so is a little awkward as WSL does not use systemd so we cannot use `reboot`. Within a WSL session, we can run any Windows executable:

```
boss@Asus: ~ $ wsl.exe -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04    Running         2
  fedoraremix     Stopped         1
  Alpine          Stopped         1
  Ubuntu          Stopped         1
```

Therefore, we can use `wsl.exe` (you have to make sure to always add `.exe` when calling Windows commands or they will not work) to shutdown the currently running WSL session `wsl.exe -t Ubuntu-20.03`, but the problem is that I don't know the session name.

When we are inside a WSL session, `hostname` is something different, and so I don't know how to find the name of the currently running session that I am inside (maybe a Windows process command that tells me what process I am running from??).

Ideally, I would like a command to equate to a reboot. I guess this would have to look something like:

- Run an asynchronous command that will initiate a new session 5-10 seconds in the future to allow the previous session to fully shutdown (and that will not terminate when this session is terminated).
- Terminate the currently running session with `wsl.exe -t <my found name>`.
- A few seconds later, the new session will start up.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for `$WSL_DISTRO_NAME`?  See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1628052/1210833) for an example of its usage with `wsl.exe` from inside the WSL session.  Your "async reboot" logic looks like it is the right track to me.  The challenge will be in starting a process that survives the WSL instance termination.  Likely it will be PowerShell-based, but it may even need to be a Windows Scheduled Task to survive - Not sure.

Comment: I think this'll do the job. From within WSL, run `cmd.exe /c "wsl.exe --terminate $WSL_DISTRO_NAME"` to terminate current WSL distro.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @NotTheDr01ds, I did not know about that variable. Handles the shutdown perfectly thanks.

Comment: @Umair, you are incorrect in your answer for the `cmd.exe /c` part. Try it and see. WSL allows running commands from Windows without having to have the `cmd.exe` part. You can essentially run any Windows binary that is on the Windows path directly. If you do `echo $PATH`, you will see that all of the Windows paths are imported there when the WSL session starts.

Comment: @YorSubs Thanks for correction about `cmd.exe /c` part.

Comment: To list running distros: `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wsl.exe -l -v --running` (verbose) or `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wsl.exe -l -q --running` (only show distro name). If you want to extract the distro name part you have to remove Windows carriage return and 0-bytes before passing to i.e. `awk` like so: `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wsl.exe -l -v --running | tr -d '[\0\r] | awk '/\*/ { print $2 }'`. If `awk` feels daunting you can try `grep / cut | head | tail` of course. `awk` explained, find the line starting with an asterix `*`, then print the second field (separated by whitespace).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Credits to the commenters above.*

### To shutdown a session from within a WSL guest, you can run:

```
wsl.exe --terminate $WSL_DISTRO_NAME
```

**Rebooting** is also possible, however so far I do not know how to get a new terminal ***inside the same console window***. The following will reboot the WSL guest and open a new console window of it when it has finished:

```
cd /mnt/c/ && cmd.exe /c start "rebooting WSL" cmd /c "timeout 5 && wsl -d $WSL_DISTRO_NAME" && wsl.exe --terminate $WSL_DISTRO_NAME
```

**Explanation**:

- From the perspective of Windows, WSL systems are mounted as network resources. `cmd` does not support the resulting UNC path formats such as `\\wsl$\Debian\<...>`. Therefore it may be best to `cd` to a directory it can resolve as a Windows path instead, such as `C:\`, before it is executed. If ommited, cmd will complain and change its directory to `cmd`'s `%windir%`.
- `&&` runs another command after the previous one has finished in linux and windows `cmd`.
- `cmd.exe /c` starts a `cmd` instance and tells it to execute a command that follows.
- `start "<WindowTitle>" ...` is a `cmd`-internal command to run another program inside its own window, independent of the `cmd` instance. In this case the program is *another* `cmd` window. **It will not be affected when WSL shuts down.**
- In the original Linux-Terminal, the first `cmd /c` command has finished, and the third command after `&&` shuts down the guest like above.
- The second `cmd` window waits for a few seconds, then starts a new WSL session of the same WSL machine.

### Creating an Alias

You can make this easier to use by creating an alias. For `bash` users, edit your `~/.bashrc` file and apply the changes afterwards:

```
nano ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

Add either or both of the lines below anywhere in the file.

You can of course choose any name you want. Both `shutdown` and `reboot` exist as systemd commands, but since they do not work in WSL machines, you can replace them with an alias as follows:

```
alias shutdown='wsl.exe --terminate $WSL_DISTRO_NAME'
alias reboot='cd /mnt/c/ && cmd.exe /c start "rebooting WSL" cmd /c "timeout 5 && wsl -d $WSL_DISTRO_NAME" && wsl.exe --terminate $WSL_DISTRO_NAME'
```

Comment: This is really good. I adjusted it a little so that the title of the Window is renamed to represent the distro. `cd /mnt/c/ && cmd.exe /c start "Rebooting WSL" cmd /c "timeout 5 && title "$WSL_DISTRO_NAME" && wsl -d $WSL_DISTRO_NAME" && wsl.exe --terminate $WSL_DISTRO_NAME`

Comment: Does not work: `wsl.exe: command not found`.  Note: For security reason `/mnt/c` and executing Windows binaries is administratively disabled (on the Windows side).  All I have is `ssh` access to the Linux, with full root.  If you want to try it yourself: 
 In `/etc/wsl.conf` set `[automount]
enabled=false` and `[interop]
enabled=false`

Comment: @Tino I guess it might not work if you are not starting from a shell that has windows admin privileges. Definitely still works for me, and I always use an admin terminal on windows.

Comment: any ideas on how to bypass AUTOMOUNT DISABLED? I have the same problem because I do not want to have the widows drives (c, d, etc) exposed to WSL...

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the ansver from @BasementScience

To manage a remote WSL I've set up a Windows TaskScheduler job to start wsl with an `/etc/init-wsl` which in turn starts `cron`, `ssh`, `rsyslog` and `autossh` (so I can connect back to WSL).

So naturally I'm keen to get these processes started also on a remote WSL reboot, so I'm able to login again afterwards.

```bash
# Added to $HOME/.bashrc - Renamed aliases to separate from OS commands
alias wslshutdown='wsl.exe --terminate $WSL_DISTRO_NAME'
alias wslreboot='cd /mnt/c/ && cmd.exe /c start "Rebooting WSL" cmd /c "timeout 5 && wsl -d $WSL_DISTRO_NAME" -- sudo /etc/init-wsl && wsl.exe --terminate $WSL_DISTRO_NAME'
```

The detail is here `... & wsl -d $WSL_DISTRO_NAME" -- sudo /etc/init-wsl & ...`

This will not start a new shell, but will start my processes so I can login again.

The `/etc/init-wsl` script have to be created:

```bash
sudo touch /etc/init-wsl && sudo chmod 755 /etc/init-wsl

# Add services as needed
sudo bash -c 'cat << EOF > /etc/init-wsl
service ssh start
service cron start
EOF'
```

```bash
# Ensure your user (the %sudo group) can sudo the init script without password
sudo bash -c 'cat << EOF > /etc/sudoers.d/user-service
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service *
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init-wsl
EOF'
```

Comment: I would appreciate see that project with the Task Scheduler setup and scripts; have you setup a github repo with this information if you are happy to share?

Comment: Using Task Scheduler I found on Stack Overflow. Basically create a job in Task Scheduler which runs `wsl.exe` with `sudo /etc/init-wsl`. You need to allow sudo without password, most tutorials cover this.

Comment: It is enough to start `cron` as everything else can be done from crontab `@reboot`.